# array_diff not taking in an array

Tags: php, arrays

This works

```
$arr = array_merge(array_diff($words, array("the","an"));
```

Why doesn't this work?

$common consists of 40 words in an array.

```
$arr = array_merge(array_diff($words, $common));
```

Is there another solution for this?

**For Reference:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$str1= "the engine has two ways to run: batch or conversational. In batch, expert system has all the necessary data to process from the beginning";

common_words($str1);

function common_words(&$string) { 

    $file = fopen("common.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    $common = array();

    while(!feof($file)) {
      array_push($common,fgets($file));
    }
    fclose($file);
    $words = explode(" ",$string);
    $arr = array_merge(array_diff($words, array("the","an")));
    print_r($arr);
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is inside `$common`? Keys, values? Does `$words` have as many items as `$common`?

Comment: Make sure $common is a 1d array

Comment: What happens when using the second approach? It doesn't work isn't too explanatory and the code looks fine.

Comment: I get the same array. it does not compute the difference of arrays

Comment: array_merge does nothing here, you can remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### White-spaces are evil, sometimes..

`fgets` with only one parameter will return one line of data from the filehandle provided.

Though, it will not strip off the trailing new-line (`"\n"` or whatever EOL character(s) is used) in the line returned.

Since `common.txt` seems to have one word per line, this is the reason why php won't find any matching elements when you use `array_diff`.

> **[PHP: fgets - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)**
>
> parameter: length
>
> **Reading ends** when length - 1 bytes have been read, **on a newline (which is included in the return value)**, or on EOF (whichever comes first). If no length is specified, it will keep reading from the stream until it reaches the end of the line.

**Rephrase**:

- All entries off `$common` will have a trailing line-break the way you are doing it now.

---

### Alternative solutions 1

If you are not going to process the entries in `common.txt` I'd recommend you to take a look at php's function `file`, and use that in conjunction with `array_map` to `rtrim` the lines for you.

```
$common = array_map ('rtrim', file ('common.txt')); // will do what you want
```

---

### Alternative solutions 2

After [@MarkBaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584) saw the solution above he made a comment saying that you might as well pass a flag to `file` to make it work in the same manner, there is no need to call array_map to "fix" the entries returned.

```
$common = file ('common.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: Read the comment carefully, particularly the bit about new lines... then check var_dump's string lengths against the length of words that you see

Comment: Yes, after observing the lengths it was different. This solution worked, though you have got an extra end bracket there :)

Comment: @asdgfassagas Will fix it, thanks for letting me know. (I never run the code examples I write on this site, which leads to typos such as that) :)

Comment: Or use the FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES flag with file()

Comment: @MarkBaker Nice one, will add it as an example snippet.

Comment: @refp - well done for spotting the problem in the first place